# Are the upvotes from when we don't have enough reputation to upvote actually lost?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, up-votes

I had made quite a large number of upvotes before recently gaining the minimum 15 reputation points required to upvote, but now I can't see my past upvotes anywhere. This is very annoying because I had put quite some effort into choosing which posts to upvote. There was always a message that the upvotes would be visible once I get at least 15 reputation points. Could you please fix this bug? Hopefully, so that the fix works also retrospectively.

[image: The message]

Comment: Before you have 15 reps, you can't upvote. So before you get 15 reps, all your upvotes are lost right after you vote.

Comment: Then why is there this message stating that these are recorded and will be visible after I reach 15 reps? Is it just straight up lying then?

Comment: I would guess that probably, this is a huge bug because there are a lot of votes cast by people with under 15 reps.

Comment: I don't have the message to see. If it is saying you will have the upvote back if you pass 15, then it is clearly and very wrong. Read more https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41347/410270. 15 rep is required to cast a vote, and the system won't save upvotes from below-15 and downvotes from below-125. This is not a bug, this is a feature.

Comment: You don't see this message because you have above 15 reps. It is saying what you said. You can probably also see it if you go to a Stack Exchange site where you have a small enough reputation and try to upvote a post. So we agree that this definitely needs to be fixed. I think probably also on the other Stack Exchange sites. Do you know how I could now move this to the general Stack Exchange meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: There are no automatic way to migrate this. Please attach a screenshot of the message. I am now more than 200 rep, so whenever I go to a new site, I automatically got 100 [Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/410270) rep, so I can never reproduce the message anymore.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the message. I will now ask this question in the global meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: They are recorded, yes, but for satistics and moderator-only information. They will never be casted officially.

Comment: Oh, wow. And why would anyone care about it? What do they do with them?

Comment: There are many SE scripts that run everyday on 3 am UTC which may collect this information. After that they will decide if the votes are questionable or irregular etc, and report it to the moderators. Moderators will look at the satistics to make decisions. For further info, ask the moderators themselves, I am not a moderator so I can not say anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a duplicate of
[Message for upvotes is misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271919/message-for-upvotes-is-misleading)
but I can't mark it as such because it is on a different SE--the global meta one.

Answer (score 3):

As the message box suggests, the votes are recorded, but never displayed. Note that [we have a large contingent of users that have very little reputation (below 15)](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1044754/how-many-users-with-rep-less-than-15) (actually every network has). These are often only visitors to the site who get what they want (or not) and then leave; of course, this could also include illegitimate users, so recording votes from them might unnecessarily skew scores.

I think one can find these votes in the [PostFeedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244) database. Here's a tally of the [total 
up-/down-votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1044764/counts-of-different-votes-from-post-feedback):

[image]

Above, 2 = UpMod (up-vote) and 3 = DownMod (down-vote).